# Setting an Explicit start of Week in Pandas DateTime module

Tags: python, pandas

I've been searching through SO and the pandas documentation with little success.

I'm attempting to find a way to set an explicit start of week and end of week in pandas datetime

basically I want my week to start on Saturday and end on Friday.

take the following df

```
  import pandas as pd
    data = {'Dates' : ['2018-10-20', '2018-10-19']}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    print(df)
    Dates
0   2018-10-20
1   2018-10-19
```

if i use dt.week I get

```
  df['Week'] = df.Dates.dt.week
    print(df)
    Dates   Week
0   2018-10-20  42
1   2018-10-19  42
```

the 19th is a Friday & the 20th is a Saturday

my desired output is

```
   df['Week'] = df.Dates.dt.week
    print(df)
    Dates   Week
0   2018-10-20  43
1   2018-10-19  42
```

is there a way to achieve this using pandas native functionality or would a function be required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can shift `2` days:

```
df['Week'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Dates']).shift(2, freq='d').week
print(df)
        Dates  Week
0  2018-10-20    43
1  2018-10-19    42
```

Comment: Thanks! figured it out, you are a star Jezrael.

Answer (score 2):

You can adding 2 days

```
(df.Dates+pd.Timedelta(days=2)).dt.week
Out[215]: 
0    43
1    42
Name: Dates, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks Wen, both solutions worked and seem equally eloquent so I'll green tick the first answer. Thank you though, you are the man.

Comment: just realised that your answer was first.. sorry @Wen-Ben